# Using $.ajax to submit a form to one of two locations

Tags: html, ajax, jquery

I have two forms, which I have combined into one; parts of the form change depending on the drop down menu choice the user has selected (tech support or sales). I would like to use the $.ajax function however I noticed there is only one url: used. Can I use an if condition here??

Answer (score 3):

Build the url first and then pass it to $.ajax

```
var postURL = "";

if (Whatever)
{
    postURL = "URL1";
}
else
{
    postURL = "URL2";
}

$.ajax({
  url: postURL,
  context: document.body,
  success: function(){
    $(this).addClass("done");
  }
});
```

Comment: Simple, elegant, doesn't gum up (sometimes complicated) ajax calls.  +1

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your call to $.ajax in a coditional like so:

```
if (condition) {
  $.ajax() // page 1
} else {
  $.ajax() // page 2
}
```